# Python Bcrypt password checking

Tags: python, hash, fastapi, bcrypt

Good afternoon. I'm trying to make authorization on fast api using bcrypt for hashing passwords. And here's he problem. I wrote the handler that receives user's email and password, then it takes all the users that have the simmilar email. And after it, it checks the passwords. But everytime I want to check it, it shows me "user doesn't exist". Does anybody knows what can be the problem? I'd really apreciate it if you'll tell me.

Here's my code:

authorization handler

```py
@auth_router.get('/auth', status_code=200, responses={404: {}})
def auth_user(email: str, password: str):
    password = password.encode('utf-8')

    user = get_user_by_email(email=email)

    if user is None:
        return ['none']
    if not bcrypt.checkpw(password, user.password):
        return ["user doesn't exists"]
    return user
```

reveiving user in email function

```py
def get_user_by_email(email: str):
    user = None
    with session.begin() as sess:
        user = sess.query(User).filter_by(email=email).one()
        sess.expunge_all()
    return user
```

Also, here's my add user function(that hashs the password)

```py
@users_router.post("/api/users/", status_code=200)
def add_new_user(user: UserModel, response: Response = None):
    """
        Adds users into db

        :param user: nick+password+email
        :param response: response exit code
        :return: None
        """

    user.password = bcrypt.hashpw(
        base64.b64encode(sha3_512(user.password.encode()).digest()),
        bcrypt.gensalt()
    )

    new_user = User(**user.dict())
    add(new_user)
```

Comment: Based on your description of what you want to accomplish, I would expect to see a loop where you are checking the password against a list of possible user.passwords.  I don't see that loop in your authorization handler.

Comment: 1) Get rid of sha3. 2) If you base64 *encode* the output you've got to base64 *decode* it after you retrieve it from the DB before you pass it to checkpw. 3) You need to utf-8 encode the putative password before checking.

Comment: @Cross: it was you who wrote *takes all the users that have the similar email.*

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk. So, ok, thanks, I think I got it. But I don't understand where should I decode password? Like this: _if not bcrypt.checkpw(password, user.password.decode('base64')):_? But if I do this, it gives me error

Comment: Actually I see this line: `base64.b64encode(sha3_512(user.password.encode()).digest()),` and I think it needs to be replaced with just `user.password` except I'm not really sure what's in `user.password`. Regardless, just follow the example on the bcrypt page. There's no reason to base64 encode the password or hash it prior to passing it to bcrypt. You should not need to base64 encode or decode anything.

Comment: wow, thanks man, You are really helped me! Now everything works!

Comment: Actually, I see now that bcrypt is limited to passwords of 72 characters of length. This is a good reason to hash the password exactly like you were doing. If you do this, you must hash the password to be checked the same way, i.e. `bcrypt.checkpw(base64.b64encode(sha3_512(password).digest()), user.password)`